# Clickable banner/ header image in Setup program

Tags: installation, inno-setup, nsis

I need to make an Windows installer either with NSIS or InnoSetup. The customer wants an image to be displayed in the installer dialogues/ wizard pages and the image needs to be clickable, e.g. open a browser window when clicked. 
Is this possible? If yes, is it also possible to use animated gifs?

Comment: Well, speaking about InnoSetup, those dialogs would have been to be replaced by custom ones (since they're Windows') and that is from script impossible. On wizard pages it's not a problem. Animated GIFs, no support without some extension.

Comment: Could you provide me a link or a small example on how to make the banner image clickable? I can't find anything on Google.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by banner image. Rather post a screenshot of how would you imagine that banner. For instance [`the top area`](http://i.imgur.com/qskGJ.png) ?

Comment: I thought about the banner on the left of the first page http://tinypic.com/r/vrsm11/6 but an example for the top area would be nice too :)

Comment: mmmm, breakfast burger... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the welcome page's left image *clickable*, you can use the following:

```
[Code]
procedure OnBannerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, 
    ErrorCode);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Cursor := crHand;
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.OnClick := @OnBannerClick;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

....and the same thing for NSIS:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW MakeClickableWizardImage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW MakeClickableWizardImage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function OnWizardClick
ExecShell "" "http://example.com"
FunctionEnd

Function MakeClickableWizardImage
StrCpy $0 $mui.WelcomePage.Image
${If} $mui.FinishPage.Image <> 0
    StrCpy $0 $mui.FinishPage.Image
${EndIf}
${NSD_OnClick} $0 OnWizardClick
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement a gif image, you can use this extension:

[GifCTRL 2.1](http://restools.hanzify.org/inno/gifctrl/inno_gifctrl_v2.1.zip)

It's Chinese but the example Inno script shows everything you need.

Comment: Thanks, but when compiling the test script, it throws an error: "Unknown type 'PChar'". I wish there was some other good way to show it... :(

Comment: @the_Ma5TeR , Try replacing PChar with PansiChar.